# UNION based on just one column

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, subquery, union

I want to UNION two tables based on a single column.

Assume that, I have a table called t1:

```
Id |  Name  
------------
1  |    A   
2  |    B  
3  |    C
```

And a second table called t2:

```
Id |  Name  
------------
1  |    B   
3  |    B  
5  |    B
```

I want to UNION them like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
UNION
SELECT * FROM T2
BASED ON ID
```

And I expect a result like:

```
Id |  Name  
------------
1  |    A   
2  |    B  
3  |    C 
5  |    B
```

If IDs are equal then pick the row from the first table:

Actually, I am working with tables which have 20+ columns. These tables are for demonstration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option uses `not exists`:

```
select id, name
from t1
union all
select id, name
from t2
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.id = t2.id)
```

You can also use conditional aggregation - although this is more cumbersome, and probably a little less efficient:

```
select
    id,
    coalesce(
        max(case when which = 1 then name end),
        max(case when which = 2 then name end)
    ) name
from (
    select id, name, 1 which from t1
    union all
    select id, name, 2 from t2
) t
group by id
```

Comment: No doubt, it works just fine. But I wonder if there is an alternative way/keyword to do this "on the fly".

Comment: @Tayfun . . . This answers your question.  If there were a simpler way, GMB would have suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from t1
union
select id, name
from t2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name
from t1
union all
select id, name
from t2
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.id = t2.id)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
                <h6 class="card-title"><span>Category</span></h6>
                <select class="form-select" name="cat" id="sel1" onchange="giveSelection(this.value)" required />
                <option></option>
                <?php 
                    $query1 = sqlsrv_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM dbo.category");
                    while ($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query1)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row1['cat']; ?>"><span><?php echo $row1 ['catname'];?></span> </option>
              <?php } ?>
                </select>

                <h6 class="card-title"><span>Name</span></h6>
                <select class="form-select" name="name" id="sel2" required />
                <option></option>
                <?php 
                    $query2 = sqlsrv_query ($conn, "exec sample");



                    while ($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query2)){
                ?>
                <option data-option="<?php echo $row2['cat']; ?>"><span><?php echo $row2 ['name'];?></span> </option>
              <?php } ?>
                </select>

                <?php 
                    $query3 = sqlsrv_query ($conn, "exec sample");



                    while ($row3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query3)){
                ?>


                <h6 class="card-title"><span>Selling Price</span></h6>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name ="price" value="" disabled/ >

                      <?php } ?>

                <h6 class="card-title"><span>Grams</span></h6>
                <input type="text" name="kilo" class="form-control" placeholder="---required for menu---">

                <h6 class="card-title"><span>Quantity</span></h6>
                <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="---required for grocery---">

                <h6 class="card-title"><span>Price</span></h6>
                <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" disabled />
                <br>

            <div align="right">
              <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cancel&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>&nbsp;

              <button type="submit" name="submit0" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Save&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

ON SELLING PRICE HOW CAN I DISPLAY JUST THE VALUE OF THE PRICE FROM MY STORE PROCEDURE WITH UNION ALL

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31138640)